# JAXB within an applet - package-info.class not found

Tags: java, applet, jaxb

We have a web application that uses JAXB from inside an applet.  Everything works fine, except when the JAXBContext is first created, we see the following logged in the applet console:

```
Creating JAXBContext...
network: Connecting https://myserver.com/MyApp/CC.ccc with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting https://myserver.com/MyApp/CC.ccc with cookie "__utma=69126149.1559268128.1262793475.1265211768.1271711769.3; JSESSIONID=723072c1c4bbc2598e402b3f24a5d12f3324"
network: Cache entry not found [url: https://myserver.com/MyApp/com/comm/servlet/generated/package-info.class, version: null]
network: Connecting https://myserver.com/MyApp/com/comm/servlet/generated/package-info.class with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://myserver.com:443/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting https://myserver.com/MyApp/com/comm/servlet/generated/package-info.class with cookie "__utma=69126149.1559268128.1262793475.1265211768.1271711769.3; JSESSIONID=723072c1c4bbc2598e402b3f24a5d12f3324"
```

This happens a total of 20 times, and slows down our application considerably.

I'm using the "xjc" ant task (com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask) to compile our schema into Java in the com/comm/servlet/generated/ package.  The code gets generated fine, but there is no package-info.java.  If I manually create this file and compile and package the code, the package-info.class is missing from the JAR file.

This is my XJC task:

```
<target name="generateJAXBSource">
 <taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
   <classpath>
     <fileset dir="lib/jaxb" includes="*.jar" />
   </classpath>
 </taskdef>

 <xjc schema="resources/requests/111.xsd" 
  destdir="src" 
  package="com.comm.servlet.generated"/>  
</target>
```

My XSD looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
 <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />

 <xs:element name="InfoResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element ref="WorkQueueItem" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
   </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

I've been googling all day but can't seem to figure out how to get around this.

I tried the workaround proposed [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t370370-error-compiling-package-info-java.html) to make sure package-info.java gets compiled:

... but no luck.

Can I instruct JAXB not to look for package-info.class?

How can I make sure that my manually created package-info.java ends up in the JAR file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your JAXB implementation is looking for package-info.class to process any package level annotations that might be present in your model.  There is no standard way to prevent a JAXB implementation from looking for package level annotations.

Adding a package-info class (in the same package as your model classes) seems like a reasonable work around.

Is package-info failing to compile for you (if so what error are you getting)?  Or is it just not appearing in your JAR (if so how are you building your JAR)?